# Comparing the sum of two ArrayLists of objects using 'compareTo'

Tags: java

I need to write code that allows a user to compare 2 hands of cards to find out which has the most valuable ones over-all. I have a class for the Card objects which each have a value and then a class for the Hand objects, storing a number of cards as an ArrayList.

The result needs to be answered by using the following code:  int comparison = hand1.compareTo(hand2); and so my code to solve this need to be in the compareTo method of the Hand class.

I've started to do a for-each loop but it doesn't seem to recognise 'mouse' here as an ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Hand implements Comparable<Hand> {
    private ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public Hand(ArrayList hand) {

    }

    public void add(Card card) {
        hand.add(card);
    }

    public void print(){
        for (Card mouse : hand){
            System.out.println(mouse.toString());
        }
    }

    public void sort(){
        Collections.sort(hand);
    }

    public int compareTo(Hand mouse){
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (Card moose : hand){

            x = x + moose.getValue();
        }

        for (Card house : mouse){ // <<<<<<<< ERROR

            y = y + house.getValue();
        }
        if (x > y){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get an error saying that mouse is not an Array. But surely if it's a 'Hand' then it will be an array? I know I'm doing something dumb here but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: '*find out which has the most valuable ones over-all.*' Could you please [edit] your question and include an example for such hands?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer Homework questions are perfectly acceptable, as long as the asker demonstrates the efforts that were made, and asks a clear and suitably scoped question. I believe this to be the case here.

Comment: Since `mouse` (that name is very misleading btw) is of type `Hand` if of course can't be used like an `ArrayList` or an `Iterable` in general. You probably should use `mouse.getHand()` and provide the appropriate (read only) getter.

Comment: Btw, instead of calculating the value of a hand when trying to compare them you could calculate it once in the constructor and update it when a card is added/removed. Then the only thing to compare would be `this.value` and `otherHand.value`.

Comment: A final but very important note: `if (x > y){ return 1; } return 0;` is wrong. If `x < y` you'd return 0 which means they are equal. That breaks the general contract, i.e. if `x > y` then `y < x` (meaning if you swap hands the result should still be the same), and that will lead to problems further down the road (if the compiler/jvm doesn't detect that right away). Since the result doesn't have to be -1, 0 and 1 but "negative", 0 and "positive" you could as well just return `x - y`.

Answer (score 1):

`Hand` isn't an array or an `Iterable`. Enhanced for loops can only iterate over things where there is some notion of them being "something you can iterate over".

The fact there is a `List<Card>` in the class is irrelevant - you have to tell Java how to iterate over an instance of your class, because you may not want it to iterate over that list; or perhaps there are many lists, so there is not a single one to pick.

Make it implement `Iterable<Card>`:

```
public class Hand implements Comparable<Hand>, Iterable<Card> {
  // ...

  @Override public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
    return hand.iterator();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a `List<Card>` as a field doesn't make the class `Hand` eligible for being used in a foreach. Either implement `Iterable<Card>` or provide a getter for the field. The former is more proper, the latter is easier.

```
for (Card house : mouse.getHand()) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this and I now get the error "Object cannot be converted to Card" My getter is as follows: public ArrayList getHand(){
        return hand;
    }

Comment: @AdamSmith it should be `public List<Card> getHand() { return hand; }` Don't use raw types

Comment: Brilliant done it. It's still not working for other reasons now but I will work on those myself. I just didn't know where I was going wrong with that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (final Card house : mouse.hand) {
```

instead of

```
for (Card house : mouse){ // <<<<<<<< ERROR
```

you want to iterate over the cards of the mouse, not the "mouse" object itself